# Possible fundamental dimensions in Pi Buckingham theorem

Tags: dimensional-analysis

While the Pi Buckingham is often taught in a fluid dynamics context, in which the relevant fundamental dimensions are generally : Mass, Length, Time and Temperature, it can obviously be applied to much more complex physics.
Is there a source that gives an extensive list of the possible fundamental dimensions? I would presume something similar to Moles would also be a fundamental quantity?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One authority on this is NIST; they have a [webpage](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html) giving

1. length (in meter)
2. Mass (in kilogram)
3. time (in second)
4. electric current (in ampere)
5. thermodynamic temperature (in kelvin)
6. amount of substance  (in mole) and
7. luminous intensity (in candela)

as the SI base units, and also provide a long list of derived units expressed in terms of the base units.